# >1 client can't connect to server in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am creating a chat client in C# to be demonstrated on localhost.

Here's the relevant code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    static List<TcpListener> garabage_collection_preventor = new List<TcpListener>();
    static Dictionary<IPEndPoint, bool> address_dictionary = new Dictionary<IPEndPoint, bool>();
    static int port_increment = 9999;
    static int client_id = 0;

    void start_listening()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port_increment);
            garabage_collection_preventor.Add(listen);
            listen.Start();
            TcpClient client = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
            IPEndPoint temp_end = ((IPEndPoint)listen.LocalEndpoint);
            address_dictionary.Add(temp_end, false);
            port_increment++;
            new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(connection_stuff)).Start(client);
        }
    }

    void writer(object ob,int end_point)
    {
        StreamWriter write = ob as StreamWriter;
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<IPEndPoint, bool> value in address_dictionary)
            {
                IPEndPoint index = value.Key;
                int temp = value.Key.Port;
                if (temp == end_point)
                {
                    while (address_dictionary[index] == true)
                    {
                        write.WriteLine(msg_box.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void reader(StreamReader read)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(read.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    void connection_stuff(object ob)
    {
        TcpClient client = ob as TcpClient;
        int writer_identification_endpoint = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port;

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader(stream);
        StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(stream);

        ThreadStart port_passing = delegate { writer(write, writer_identification_endpoint); };
        Thread thread = new Thread(port_passing);

        reader(read);
        thread.Start();
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int end_point = int.Parse(port.Text);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<IPEndPoint, bool> value in address_dictionary)
        {
            IPEndPoint index = value.Key;
            int temp = value.Key.Port;
            if (temp == end_point)
            {
                address_dictionary[index] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void listener_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(start_listening).Start();
        listener.Enabled = false;
    }
 }
}
```

Now the problem is that the first client can easily connect with the program and send messages which this program can easily read. However every subsequent client cannot connect.

I know that I shouldn't be making creating than one TCPListener but the problem is that I have to demonstrate the program on localhost and port number is the only true way to differentiate between client.

So please tell me what's wrong with the code I have been banging my head against the wall on it for hours.

EDIT

this is what happens when english is not a first language :)  This code(not complete presently) will be a chat client. Each instance of this code will be able to connect with other instance of this same code to communicate. Any number of instances should be able to connect with any number of instances(like if double click 5 times the program there would now be 5 instances ready to communicate with each other).

Now the problem is that every instance will have the same IP Address(Because they are all running on the same machine). The question arises how say instance 1 suppose to connect to instance 4, ip can't be used here because instance 2,3 and 5 will also have the same IP address. So what i am trying to do is to connect instance 1 with instance 4 with IP Address and PORT instead of just using just the IP Address as is the case with a single TCPListener.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TcpListener/TcpClient stops processing data under certain circumstances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404803/tcplistener-tcpclient-stops-processing-data-under-certain-circumstances)

Answer (score 5):

Try moving these three lines of code outside the while(true) loop in your start_listening routine.

```
TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port_increment);
garabage_collection_preventor.Add(listen);
listen.Start();
```

You only need one listener, from which you accept many different connections.

Comment: As i said in my post i can't make single TCP listener. As the program will run on localhost It is requirement that i must make multiple TCPlistener being able to listen for client depending upon port and not on IP(as all clients on localhost will have same address). Any other suggestions.

Comment: @WinCoder your concept is incorrect. A single listener listening on a single port can serve as many clients as it likes. The only difference is whether it does so in a loop (iterative server) or creates a new thread/process (concurrent) for each client. After every accept call you get a new connected socket with a particular client. Each client would have its own source ip and port, to which the connected listener responds. A simple e.g. is google web server, all clients connect to it at port 80 and it handles them in the best possible fashion.

Comment: as i have said innumerable times that this is not a real world program it is only supposed to work on localhost where all the instances of the program will have same IP. So no i can't listen for all on the clients on the same port because then i would not be able to distinguish between them(because all of them have the same IP unlike on an webserver where all the clients have unique IP). Anyways this question is no longer relevant as i have solved my problem by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
void start_listening()
{
    TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port_increment);
    garabage_collection_preventor.Add(listen);
    listen.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
        // etc
    }
}
```

That is, once you have created your listener, it runs in the loop accepting incoming connections from the client.

Edit: The problem you are having is because your simulation is flawed. In the real world, each chat server runs in a single O/S instance, on one, known, port number. Because you only have one O/S instance yourself, you can't run multiple chat servers on that instance all listening on the same port. But something like this might work, i.e., you need two loops, the first one to create your listeners, and the second inner loop for each listener to accept multiple clients. Note: these loops need exit conditions!

```
void start_listening()
{
    while (true)
    {
        TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port_increment);
        garabage_collection_preventor.Add(listen);
        listen.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
            IPEndPoint temp_end = ((IPEndPoint)listen.LocalEndpoint);
            address_dictionary.Add(temp_end, false);
            new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(connection_stuff)).Start(client);
        }
        port_increment++;
    }
}
```

Comment: My program will run on localhost and multiple clients will connect with each other. As all the clients would have same IP, the only differentiable character would be the port through which they connect. The problem with a single TCPListener is that it would only monitor a single port. So i can't use the single TCPListener solution. Please is there any other way